# SSID will not show up on Ubuntu MATE

Tags: live-usb

I am running off a live USB on a mac, and I checked to make sure I had the correct drivers I needed, I did. I can't for some reason get the wifi to work, my SSIDs will not show up. When I boot to Mac, they all show up, but none appear on Ubuntu MATE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed to do was "Install" the drivers. To do that, I opened the Installer, and checked the "Install 3rd party drivers while installing".

I clicked continue, and then I waited for the drivers to install. This installed all the drivers I needed. This works on Ubuntu as well as Ubuntu MATE.